# Різниця між «хоч» і «хоча»

Tags: різниця-між-словами, сполучники, милозвучність

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах каже, що «хоч» і «хоча» — повні синоніми:

> [**ХОЧ** 1, **ХОЧА**](http://sum.in.ua/s/khoch). *спол[учник].*
>   <…>
>   **ХОЧ** 2, **ХОЧА**. *част[ка].*
>   <…>

Відповідно, вибір між ними обумовлюється винятково милозвучністю (преференціями мовця).

Але ставлячи «хоча» з позицій милозвучності, я іноді ловив себе на думці: «Чи не звучатиме це „хоча“ тут якось дивно (хоч і милозвучно)?» А нещодавно взагалі натрапив на випадок, коли «хоча» видається мені зовсім недоречним:

> *[Обговорюючи різні варіанти:]*
>   Так користувач хоч зможе <…>, а так — [взагалі] не зможе нічого.

Хоча додавання «а» перед «зм» видається навіть милозвучнішим (чи принаймні обидва варіанти мають бути прийнятними з точки зору семантики) — мені оте «так користувач хоча зможе…» видається неприйнятним. Це особисте викривлення сприйняття — чи «хоч» і «хоча» справді неповні синоніми, а словник помиляється?

Comment: Тут я у разі використання "хоча" додав би ще й "б": "користувач хоча б зможе". Може тут для милозвучності "б" прибрано, щоб не було "хоч б зможе"?

Comment: @Artemix, так, я теж про це думав. Що повний варіант: «хоч би зможе» / «хоча б[и] зможе». Тим не менш — укорочений варіант (без «б[и]») сприймається лише з «хоч». Чому? Чи обидва вкорочені варіанти неправильні?

Comment: @обставинниковийТранспозитор, насправді, було б краще, якби Ви показали, що «хоча» (без «б[и]») справді не вживається (чи вживається значно рідше, ніж «хоч») у ролі видільної частки в українській мові. Бо ті сайти — то таке, навіть у наведеній цитаті містять одрук, не кажучи вже про те, що вони прямо цього не стверджують, а просто не наводять у переліку — не обов'язково повному (вони й «хоча б**и**» там не наводять, хоч воно [вживається](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22хоча+би%22)). Але — все одно дякую :). Тож я поки що не приймаю (раптом хтось детальніше) — але плюсую.

Answer (score 8):

В поданому Вами прикладі *хоч* є *часткою*, а саме видільною (чи підсилювально-видільною). Про це, наприклад, [каже](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/chastka/6-1-0-153) сайт "Офіційний сайт української мови":

> Частки, які надають окремому слову чи групі слів певного смислового
>   відтінку (присловесні частки), за значенням є такі:
>
> а) підсилювально-видільні — вживаються для підсилення або виділення
>   окремих слів у реченні: навіть, тільки, лише {лиш), всього-на-всього,
>   **хоч**, **хоча б**, принаймні, аж, же (ж), -таки, -то, все, ще, вже, вже й, і, та, собі, о, ой.

Як бачимо, такої частки, як *хоча*, немає, вона існує лише в поєднанні з *б*, тобто *хоча б*. Тому в цьому реченні *хоч* можна замінити на *хоча б*.

Аналогічно [пише](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)), до прикладу, "Вікіпедія" або ж [сайт](http://ukr-mova.at.ua/index/chastka/0-20) "Правила української мови".